# Tangent space to a linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry

the tangent space to a linear algebraic group $G$ in $\Bbb A^n_K$ is a vector space. is $T_PG$ also a $K$-algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Since any $K$-vector space is a $K$-algebra by component-wise multiplication, the answer is formally "yes". However, this $K$-algebra structure appears to be of little importance, it is much more relevant to the study of linear algebraic groups that $T_1G$ is a [Lie Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra), where $1\in G$ denotes the neutral element.